# Why am I getting 404 with Rust in docker

Tags: docker, rust, docker-compose, actix-web

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
# Build stage
FROM rust:slim-buster as builder

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y pkg-config make g++ libssl-dev cmake libmariadb-dev-compat openssl && \
  rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

WORKDIR /var/www/app

COPY . .

RUN cargo build
# Prod stage, removing the Rust toolchain
FROM gcr.io/distroless/cc
COPY --from=builder /var/www/app/config /config
COPY --from=builder /var/www/app/target/debug/my-app /

CMD ["./my-app"]
```

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  
  my-app:
    container_name: my-app
    image: my-app
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8088:8088'
    expose:
      - '8088'
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mosquitto
      - db

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    expose:
      - "6379"
    
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.15
    container_name: mosquitto
    user: mosquitto
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./config/
        target: /mosquitto/config/
    # - type: bind
    #   source: ./log/
    #   target: /mosquitto/log/
      - type: volume
        source: data
        target: /mosquitto/data
    ports:
      - target: 1883
        published: 1883
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 9001
        published: 9001
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
  
  db:
    container_name: sqlite3
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      #Modify following line
      - ./config/isumis.db:/config
    ports:
      - '9000:9000' # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
    expose:
      - '9000'
    restart: unless-stopped

  mobsf:
    container_name: mobsf
    build: https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF.git
    image: mobsf
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"

  nodejs:
    container_name: blacklight-collector
    image: isumis/blacklight
    build: 
      context: ./blacklight-config/
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    expose:
      - "8081"
    
volumes:
  data:
    name: "mqtt-broker-data"
```

And this is my webserver with `actix`:

```
pub async fn server() -> Result<(), impl Error> {
    info!("Start backend!");

    init();
    let store: Data<DataStore> = Data::new(DataStore::default());
    info!("Swagger UI available at http://localhost:8088/api/ and http://localhost:8088/clm-core/");

    // Init actix
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(Logger::default())
            .configure(data_controller::configure(store.clone()))
            .service(
                SwaggerUi::new("/api/{_:.*}")
                    .url("/api-docs/openapi.json", ApiDoc::openapi().clone()),
            )
            .service(
                SwaggerUi::new("/clm-core/{_:.*}")
                    .external_url_unchecked("http://localhost:3006/core/swagger", json!({"openapi": "3.0.0"})),
            )
            .service(
                web::scope("/dashboard/user")
                    .service(get_user_by_id)
                    //.service(get_user_data)
            )
            .service(
                web::scope("/dashboard")
                    .service(get_all_statistics)
                    //.service(get_specific_statistics)
                    .service(static_scan)
            )
            .service(
                web::scope("/tools")
                    .service(blacklight)
                    .service(port_scanner)
                    .service(analyze_ip)
            )
            .service(
                web::scope("/init")
                    .service(create_test_user)
                    .service(api_key)
            )
    })
    .bind(("0.0.0.0", 8088))?
    .run()
    .await
}

fn init() {
    // Connect to redis
    redis_service::init();

    thread::spawn(|| {
        // Wait for new messages
        crate::service::subscriber_service::subscriber();
    });
}
```

I'm using the following dependencies:

```
bench = []
test = []
example = []

[[bin]]
path = "src/main.rs"
name = "my-app"
test = false
doctest = false
bench = false
doc = false
plugin = false
proc-macro = false
harness = true
edition = "2021"
required-features = []

[package]
name = "my-app"
edition = "2021"
version = "0.0.1"
autobins = false
autoexamples = false
autotests = false
autobenches = false

[profile.release]
lto = true
opt-level = "z"
debug = true
strip = true

[profile.dev]
debug = 2

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
async-std = "1.12.0"
cfonts = "1"
futures = "*"
isocountry = "0.3.2"
lazy_static = "*"
log = "0.4"
paho-mqtt = "0.12.1"
r2d2 = "0.8.10"
regex = "1"
serde_json = "1"
simple_logger = "*"
whois-rust = "1.5.1"
rand = "0.8.5"
dns-lookup = "2.0.2"

[dependencies.attohttpc]
version = "0.26.0"
features = ["json"]

[dependencies.redis]
version = "0.23.1"
features = ["r2d2"]

[dependencies.serde]
version = "1.0"
features = ["derive"]

[dependencies.utoipa]
version = "3.4.4"
features = ["actix_extras"]

[dependencies.utoipa-swagger-ui]
version = "3.1.5"
features = ["actix-web"]
```

I get only this warning message during `$ sudo docker compose up`:

```
[+] Running 1/1
 ! my-app Warning                                                        1.5s 
[+] Building 93.0s (14/14) FINISHED
```

All ports are exposed in my `docker-compose.yml`. If I execute the webserver locally then everything is fine. Since 2-3 days I get a `404` especially from my Rust program during execution time in Docker. All other Docker container are working fine. Is there something I'm doing wrong here; any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where's the *compose* file?

Comment: I added the file

Comment: When you build the Docker image in question, do you see any warning or error messages?

Comment: Docker shows only this: `[+] Running 1/1 ! my-app Warning                                                          1.5s [+] Building 93.0s (14/14) FINISHED` at start-up in the first three lines. But there are no specific messages.

Comment: I'm talking about [**building Docker image**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

Comment: I executed it and there are no error or warning messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255029/discussion-between-msrumon-and-jan).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using the `gcr.io/distroless/cc` distro. I changed the Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:slim-buster as builder

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y pkg-config make g++ libssl-dev cmake libmariadb-dev-compat openssl && \
  rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

WORKDIR /var/www/app

COPY . .

RUN cargo build
CMD ["cargo", "run"]
```

It works with multistage build if I add the `--release` flag to `cargo build`. Can someone explain me this?